# Create new Gnome session profile with xmonad as window manager?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, login, window, xmonad

I'm currently using Ubuntu 11.04 using the "Ubuntu Classic" session at login (Gnome 2). I recently tried xmonad as the window manager for the Gnome session, and I like it when my laptop is plugged to a big monitor; I used the method outlined [here](http://markhansen.co.nz/xmonad-ubuntu-lucid/) to get xmonad as the window manager and keep everything else Gnome. When I don't have my laptop plugged in to another monitor, I prefer metacity due to the limitations on screen real estate.

Is it possible to create two Ubuntu Classic sessions, each one using a different window manager? If so, how? I am aware there is an xmonad session in itself, but this isn't what I want as I would like all the features from gnome to be kept.

Alternatively, is it possible to change the window manager inside a session without logging out? This would be even MORE useful.

Answer (score 0):

> Alternatively, is it possible to change the window manager inside a session without logging out? This would be even MORE useful.

Not that I know of, I don't think it is possible. Logging out and in is certainly the easiest way.

As for your other questions, maybe these links will help, they seem to be on the right track:

- http://linuxexchange.org/questions/1144/running-two-window-managers-simultaneously
- http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/multiple-x.html